# How to sort keys by length in PouchDB mapreduce?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, pouchdb

I'm working on a [React app](https://github.com/dhappy/forets) to search through collections hosted in IPFS.

I am using PouchDB to store the mappings between paths and IPFS ids. The interface I'm working on is a autocomplete. Each object in my database looks something like:

```
{
  path: ['path', 'to', 'blob'],
  ipfs_id: 'Qem4u234jk34k…',
}
```

I have a design document that prints all the subpaths leading to an entry:

```
const ddoc = {
  views: {
    all: {
      // emit confuses webpack in production
      map: (
        'function(doc) {'
        + 'for(i in doc.path) {'
        + 'var path = doc.path.slice(0,i+1).join("/");'
        + 'emit(path, null);'
        + '}'
        + '}'
      ),
      reduce: function(keys, values, rereduce) {
        return 1 // uniqueness
      }.toString(),
    },
  },
}
```

My autocomplete looks like:

```
db.query(
  'paths/all',
  {
    startkey: search,
    endkey: `${search}\uFFFF`,
    limit: 25,
    group: true,
  }
)
```

I want to sort the keys by length so partial completions will come first.

My current understanding is this isn't possible, and I need to switch to storing the path length in the object and creating documents for intermediate paths. Then I could do a Mango `$gte` query with a `sort`.

Alternatively, I could try some of the methods from [storing hierarchical data](http://probablyprogramming.com/2008/07/04/storing-hierarchical-data-in-couchdb), but my path elements aren't globally unique, so I will have to assign nodes GUIDs and build paths from those.

Comment: Does your search term ever contain path separators?

Answer (score 0):

I added nodes to the database for the intermediate nodes between the root and the leaf, and stored the depth of each path in the document. *(The original design just had the leaf paths.)*

I also made the serialized path the document `_id`.

Now I am doing the completion search with a Mango query:

```
db.find({
  selector: {
    _id: {
      $gt: search,
      $lte: `${search}\uFFF0`,
    },
    depth: { $gt: null },
  },
  sort: ['depth'],
  limit: MAX_RESULTS,
})
```

It works, but takes multiple seconds to return.